# Pass nodes inside <content> to nested component element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I have two Polymer elements:

```
<polymer-element name="image-slider">
  <template>
    <content id="images" select="img">
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer('image-slider', {
    ready: function() {
      $(this.$.images.getDistributedNodes()).each(function() {
        $(this).width(100);
      });
      console.group('image-slider');
      console.log('content#images nodes: ', this.$.images.getDistributedNodes());
      console.groupEnd('image-slider');
    }
  })
  </script>
</polymer-element>


<polymer-element name="fruit-item">
  <template>
    <image-slider>
      <content id="images" select="img">
    </image-slider>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer('fruit-item', {
    ready: function() {

    }
  })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

As you can see `<fruit-item>` use `<image-slider>`.

I am trying to pass all `<img>` inside `<fruit-item>`s content to `<image-slider>`. Unfortunately it doesn't work.
It pass text node instead of `<img>`s  from `<fruit-item>`s content.

[**(DEMO)**](http://jsbin.com/facisisayuzi/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fair bit in your custom elements that you don't need at all. I did a rewrite over at http://jsbin.com/rijezabapuwe/1/edit but the gist is to not style with JS, use styling with the `:host` and `::content` shadow dom selectors. That immediately removes any need for the `ready` function that you were using, so turns your elements into `noscript` elements instead.

Comment: Problem is still occurring. Changing width via javascript was just example.

Comment: then you need to give a new, better example, because the one you illustrated your problem with was easily fixed.

Comment: In your example images in `fruit-item` are big. They should be small like in `image-slider`.
PS Are you sure you gave me correct link? It's the same I gave and I don't see any changes.

Comment: what the ... opening my link does not open the changes I had made. Let me make you a new fiddle so we can be sure it has the fixed code. Sorry about that (what the heck did jsbin do...)

Comment: jsbin updated. This should not revert to your original example since it's a new jsbin entirely. That said, comparing Chrome to Firefox shows firefox getting this wrong, so there might actually be a bug in how Polymer is shimming the `::content` selector and might require you file a bug over at https://github.com/Polymer/customelements

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, I can't access images inside `image-slider` from `fruit-item` like I wanted when changing size in my example (it could be anything. I just need access to those elements).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59680/discussion-between-ralph-gutkowski-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: Regarding the CSS issue with ::content in Firefox: You'll need to use `polyfill-next-selector` (http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#at-polyfill). Here's an updated jsbin (http://jsbin.com/rijezabapuwe/3/edit)